# Convert List of Categories into Category Tree Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, categories

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CatID   ParentID
1       0
2       1
3       2
4       3
5       0
6       1
7       2
```

And this is the result I would like to achieve:

```
Cat0   Cat1   Cat2   Cat3   Cat4   Cat5   Cat6   Cat7
1      2      3      4
5      6      7
```

How can I do this? I thought about creating a temporary table, but have no clue how to fill it with data in desired format.

Can anyone help please?

**The table with CatIDs is very long - there are 54K unique CatIDs.**

[Actual list of CatIDs in excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMFiQa8yMePdzgweTFiRDVPRXM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your data structure makes no sense.  Why isn't the hierarchy 7 --> 2 --> 1 ?  Where does 7 --> 6 --> 5 come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand.  You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when parentid = 0 then catid end) as cat0,
       max(case when parentid = 1 then catid end) as cat1,
       max(case when parentid = 2 then catid end) as cat2,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parentid order by catid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/WHXV52724).

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Indeed with the data set I have provided in my example it works. I should've stated that the list of CatIDs is very long in the first place. My apologies.

Comment: @Maciej . . . I don't see what the number of `catid` values has to do with the answer to this question.

Comment: Basically CatID is a list of unique IDs and ParentID are IDs of their immediate parents. The fact that the list is so long makes it hard to do .. for me that is :/

Comment: @Gordon the ParentID will not always be in a range from 0 to 7. Each ID can be (and usually is) a parent.

Comment: @Maciej . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  This seems to answer the question that you did ask here.  You should be very clear about what you want to do in the other question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right. Thanks again for your answer. I have rephrased my question and posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796694/how-to-create-category-tree-hierarchy-with-multiple-levels-sql